# Using Android Studio, Adding a Library to build.gradle

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I'm using Android Studio, and I'm trying to add the `slf4j library` using 
Build/Edit Libraries and Dependencies.

I clicked on the +, selected Library Dependency, and picked slf4j from the list.  Studio added the library to my `build.gradle` file like this:

```
dependencies {  
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1'  
    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-android:1.7.7'

    ...
```

But when I try to run sync, I get this error:

```
Error:(75, 10) Failed to resolve: org.slf4j:slf4j-android:1.7.7
```

Is there something else I need to do to my project to be able to use this library??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get the maven repository working with my Android Studio project (which I didn't know is what I was trying to do), I needed to add the following to build.gradle:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

Apparently, that allows the software to work out the compile commands.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out what was causing this issue for me (and likely for you, given the build file above) was the Scala plugin. There was a bug with the Scala plugin preventing Android Studio from importing Gradle projects. The fix for this has already been pushed live, so to get Android Studio working again you can either disable the Scala plugin or update it.

- Open Settings/Preferences
- Open the Plugins section on the left
- Find the Scala plugin
- Right click on the plugin and click Reload List of Plugins
- Right click on the plugin again and click Update Plugin

This allowed me to do a Gradle sync and build from Android Studio again, I hope it helps for you!

It looks like this is a bug with Android Studio. Hopefully it'll be fixed soon.

In the meantime, you can debug your application without launching it from Android Studio by attaching the debugger to a running process of the application. You can do this two ways.

- Via the menus: Run -> Attach Debugger to Android Process
- Pressing the button that is two to the right of the play/build button. It looks like a grey phone/rectangle with a little green bug in the bottom right

After you do this, a dialog will show up listing available applications to debug. Select your application and press OK. Your breakpoints should now work.

If you need to debug something that happens on app startup, you can tell Android to wait for a debugger when launching certain applications with the following steps:

- On the phone open the Android Settings
- Open the Developer Options
- Make sure Wait for debugger is checked
- Press Select debug app and choose your application

Then when you start your application, it'll wait for you to attach a debugger via one of the two methods mentioned above.

Hope this helps!

Comment: You could ask first if you the Scala plugin is installed considering it isn't there on a fresh Android Studio install

Comment: Thanks for the very detailed answer, but unfortunately it doesn't appear that I have the Scala plugin.

Comment: ... And just to really turn the screws, it doesn't appear that my Android has a "Wait for debugger" option in its developer options...